# How to calculate different discounts on range of products

Tags: c++

I have a structrue as below,

```
struct ProductDetails
{
    string name;
    double actualPrice;
    double finalPrice;
}product;
```

I have different products say, product name ={Apple, bag of Carrot, Orange, sale bag of beans, cake, sale bag of grapes,cookie}

so in these products,

fruits and vegies have 2% discount
others has 4% discount.
Product starts with 'sale' has extra 10% discount on top of its category(how to write generic code for one starts with 'sale').

```
//PART OF THE CODE
{
    std::vector<ProductDetails> itemsV;

    // some logic here and got all the ProductDetails

    itemsV.pushback(product);
    for(auto &item: itemsV)
    {
        if(item.name == ("Apple" || "bag of Carrot" || "Orange"))
        {
            item.finalPrice = discount(item.price,2,0);
        }
        else if(item.name == ("sale bag of beans" || "sale bag of grapes"))
        {
           item.finalPrice = discount(item.price,2,10);
        }
        else
        {
            item.finalPrice = discount(item.price,4,0);
        }
        // do something with the finalPrice.
    }
}
```

I would like to know any other better and efficient way to do the above job.

Below is the template of calculating the final price after discount with three different arguments.
//original Price, discount percentage, additional discount.

```
double discount(double op, float dp=0.0, float additional=0.0)
        {
            // calculate discount and return final price
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I was you I would add an enum for the items you wish to group rather than string matches, and add this to your struct. But you have stated this isn't an option

```
struct ProductDetails
{
    string name;
    double actualPrice;
    double finalPrice;
}product;
```

Then create a map between FoodType and discount

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, double> discountMap;
```

Then you can apply a discount to the food type and apply it all at once. Something like this, note not using a compiler just banging it out so you might need to fix-up a bit but it should be mostly right

```
for(auto &item: itemsV)
{
    auto it = discountMap.find(item.name);
    if (it != discountMap.end()){
        item.finalPrice = item.actualPrice * discountMap.at(item.name);
    }
}
```

Then just set your discounts and you're good to go.

```
//Should implicitly convert to a std::string
discountMap["Carrots"] = 0.9; //90% of value or 10% discount
```

Comment: But I get input only as Carrot, oranges and anything not as it's categories fruits or vegetables like you added in enum. In such scenario how to group all given fruits as fruits and map it with discount. And the items(carrots, oranges etc) are already stored in the  struct product.name which isn't used in the example you have shared.Thanks.

Comment: This would be added to the user interface, rather than a console app that takes strings you'd have a selection that narrows by food type then select food type. In your example you have to know all food names before the user enters anything, so it's crazy to make them type anything rather just select with mouse. The the app would have an input section that the user enters food name, and selects food type to add new items. Lastly this would be written to disk in a database or json file so to add or remove items you don't recompile your code.

Comment: But if this is just a homework question rather than how would you design an application that does this, ignore all that.

Comment: Yes that's the best way, but In my case I need to perform all this in console only with the given inputs. So this is where I am struck.

Comment: You can use the same code just instead of an enum, use the string. std::map<std::string, double> discountMap; then discountMap["Carrot"] = 0.9;, altohugh you'd probably use an unordered_map since it won't be ordered by default like an enum. Updated the code above

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
if (item.name.find("sale") == 0) {
...
```

This checks if the string starts with sale. See [find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)

**edit**: I was assuming this is some school assignment in which the struct is not changeable. If you can add fields to the struct, the other answer is the way to go.